# visual studio: copy *.pdb of the project references from some directory to TargetDir

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

There are few solutions (business logic etc) that copies their *.dll and *.pdb to some directories.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
<PostBuildEvent>copy $(TargetPath) $(DllDir)\*.*

copy $(TargetDir)*.pdb $(SymbolsFolder)\*.pdb </ PostBuildEvent> </ PropertyGroup>
```

there are few GUI-solutions that references these dlls (not each and every just few of them)
for better debugging experience it would be great to have ability during compile time or after successful build to copy *.pdb of referenced assemblies from $(SymbolsFolder) to bin/debug directory of building GUI-project

something like this in GUI's  *.csproj file:

```
  <Target Name="Compile">

<MSBuild Projects="@(Reference)" Targets="Build" >
  copy  $(SymbolsFolder)\'%(Name)'.pdb $(TargetDir)*.pdb
</MSBuild>
```

this code doesn't work. Can you help me to correct this pseudo-code please?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{15E44798-6182-44B0-9302-C96532A334FF}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>GuiControls</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>GuiControls</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>true</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>test21.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug_x86|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug_x86\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug_x86|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug_x86\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Releasex86|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\Releasex86\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Releasex86|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Releasex86\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Accessibility" />
    <Reference Include="Pr21BusinessObjects5">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsProduct21\Pr21BusinessObjects5.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Pr21BusinessObjects5.DataAccess">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsProduct21\Pr21BusinessObjects5.DataAccess.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Pr21BusinessObjectsFlat">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsProduct21\Pr21BusinessObjectsFlat.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Pr21Common">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsProduct21\Pr21Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Product21.Datamodel">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsProduct21\Product21.Datamodel.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Product21.Factory">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsProduct21\Product21.Factory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Product21.Utilities">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsProduct21\Product21.Utilities.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Product21CodingLists">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsProduct21\Product21CodingLists.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Pr21Interfaces">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsProduct21\Pr21Interfaces.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Pr21UtilsHelpers">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsProduct21\Pr21UtilsHelpers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="BusinessObjects">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsProduct21\BusinessObjects.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ConfigurationProduct21, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=549588756ec70082, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsProduct21\ConfigurationProduct21.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="InfragisticsWPF4.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.2406, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsExternal\Infragistics\Infragistics2013\SharedXAML\InfragisticsWPF4.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart.v13.1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.2406, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsExternal\Infragistics\Infragistics2013\WPFOnly\InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v13.1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="InfragisticsWPF4.DataVisualization.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.2406, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsExternal\Infragistics\Infragistics2013\SharedXAML\InfragisticsWPF4.DataVisualization.v13.1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="InfragisticsWPF4.Editors.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.2406, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsExternal\Infragistics\Infragistics2013\WPFOnly\InfragisticsWPF4.Editors.v13.1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="InfragisticsWPF4.v13.1, Version=13.1.20131.2406, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsExternal\Infragistics\Infragistics2013\WPFOnly\InfragisticsWPF4.v13.1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Expression.Interactions, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsExternal\Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.mshtml, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.Prism">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsExternal\Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsExternal\Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Interactivity.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsExternal\Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsExternal\Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsExternal\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.Unity">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Product21Projects2018\DllsExternal\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\NLog.4.0.0\lib\net45\NLog.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PresentationUI, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="Prism, Version=7.1.0.431, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40ee6c3a2184dc59, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Prism.Core.7.1.0.431\lib\net45\Prism.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ReachFramework" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.IO.Compression" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Printing" />
    <Reference Include="System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.3.0\lib\netstandard1.0\System.ValueTuple.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Expression.Blend.Sdk.1.0.2\lib\net45\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Telerik.Windows.Controls, Version=2020.1.218.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="Telerik.Windows.Controls.FixedDocumentViewers, Version=2020.1.218.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="telerik.windows.controls.fixeddocumentviewersui, Version=2020.1.218.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="Telerik.Windows.Controls.ImageEditor, Version=2020.1.218.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input, Version=2020.1.218.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation, Version=2020.1.218.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="Telerik.Windows.Controls.RibbonView, Version=2020.1.218.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="Telerik.Windows.Controls.RichTextBoxUI, Version=2020.1.218.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="Telerik.Windows.Documents, Version=2020.1.218.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="Telerik.Windows.Documents.Core, Version=2020.1.212.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="Telerik.Windows.Documents.Fixed, Version=2020.1.212.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="TXTextControl, Version=19.0.1200.500, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6b83fe9a75cfb638, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Program Files\Text Control GmbH\TX Text Control 19.0.NET for WPF\Assembly\TXTextControl.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="UIAutomationProvider" />
    <Reference Include="UIAutomationTypes" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsFormsIntegration" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <None Include="Product21.snk" />
    <None Include="Pr21p.config" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <AppDesigner Include="Properties\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>copy $(TargetPath) $(Pr21DllDir)\*.*
copy $(TargetName).pdb $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\$(TargetName).pdb
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\Pr21BusinessObjects5.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.*
copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\Pr21BusinessObjectsFlat.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.*
copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\Pr21Common.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.*
copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\Pr21Constants.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.*
copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\Product21.Datamodel.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.*
copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\Product21.Factory.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.*
copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\Pr21Interfaces.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.*
copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\Pr21Styles.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.*
copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\BusinessObjects.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.*
)</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: You use MSBuild task to build some other projects and then do some operation(copy xxx.pdb files) on these projects in GUI project? Did GUI a custom csproj file or a standard c# project? And as far as I know, you can not define copy operation in MSBuild task, it is illegal.

Comment: Or please share the whole `GUI.csproj` file with us so that we can troubleshoot your issue more quickly.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT  I updated original post with *.csproj file. It's standard  WPF  project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> visual studio: copy *.pdb of the project references from some
>   directory to TargetDir

I think the main issue is that you did not define the custom property `Pr21DllDir` and `Product21SymbolsFolder` in your xxx.csproj file which I have not seen those properties in your file. So when you execute these command, MSBuild unable to identify `$(Pr21DllDir)` and `$(Product21SymbolsFolder)`.

**Solution**

You can try these:

```
       <PropertyGroup>
         <Pr21DllDir>C:\xxx\xxxx\xxx(the folder name)</Pr21DllDir>   
        <Product21SymbolsFolder>C:\xxx\xxx\xxx(the folder name)</Product21SymbolsFolder>    
        </PropertyGroup>
 <PropertyGroup>
   <PostBuildEvent>
    copy $(TargetPath) $(Pr21DllDir)\*.*
    copy $(TargetName).pdb $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\$(TargetName).pdb
    if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
    copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\Pr21BusinessObjects5.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.*
    copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\Pr21BusinessObjectsFlat.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.*
    copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\Pr21Common.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.*
    copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\Pr21Constants.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.*
    copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\Product21.Datamodel.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.*
    copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\Product21.Factory.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.*
    copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\Pr21Interfaces.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.*
    copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\Pr21Styles.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.*
    copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\BusinessObjects.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.*
    )
     </PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And make sure that the folders exists under your path. Since you have not provided the error message and if you have any other error, please share with us and we will help you solve it as soon as possible.

**Update 1**

Try to use these node instead of `PostBuildEvent` property and this function works well in my side and can match the reference dll name in **Product21SymbolsFolder** folder.

**Note**: you should remove every reference dll's `Version`,`Culture` and `PublicKeyToken` in `xxx.csproj` file.

Like:  change `<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">`

to `<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">`.

**Function**

target `test` is to split all dependencies referenced by the project

target `test1` is to match the referenced dependency in the `Product21SymbolsFolder`, match successfully, copy to the output folder.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <Pr21DllDir>C:\xxx\xx</Pr21DllDir>
    <Product21SymbolsFolder>C:\xxx\xxx</Product21SymbolsFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="test" AfterTargets="Build">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <MoreFile>
                @(Reference)
            </MoreFile>     
        </PropertyGroup>
        <ItemGroup>
            <MoreFilesArray Include="$(MoreFile.Split(';'))" />
        </ItemGroup>        
    </Target>

    <Target Name="test1" AfterTargets="test">
        <Copy SourceFiles="$(TargetPath)" DestinationFolder="$(Pr21DllDir)"></Copy>
        <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)$(TargetName).pdb" DestinationFolder="$(Product21SymbolsFolder)"></Copy>
        <Copy Condition="'$(ConfigurationName)'=='Debug' and Exists('$(Product21SymbolsFolder)\%(MoreFilesArray.Identity).pdb')" SourceFiles=" $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\%(MoreFilesArray.Identity).pdb" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)"></Copy>
    </Target>
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I have no error. Pr21DllDir and Product21SymbolsFolder exist in the Environment Variables. Problem: not to write for each dependency/reference something like copy  $(Product21SymbolsFolder)\Pr21BusinessObjects5.pdb $(TargetDir)\*.* (if there are 40 dependencies not to write manually 40 "copy" command) but AUTOMATICALLY in the loop or something like that determine name of dependency and automatically call "copy" command for this name. What is the original post about...

Comment: Did you want to match the reference dll's pdb files of the Product21SymbolsFolder folder and then copy them into the output path folder?

Comment: thank you very much for this brilliant code snippet!